# After initial click, have to click twice with Jquery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Couldn't find a solution that actually worked, but I want that on a click, a div shows. 
Now this works when I load the page, but then after that first click, I have to click twice every time for the div to show.

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setMenu();    
});

function setMenu()
{
    var headerExtIsOpen = false;
    $('#headerExt').hide();

    $('#header').click(function () {
        if (!headerExtIsOpen) {
            $('#headerExt').show();
            headerExtIsOpen = true;
        } else {    
            $('#headerExt').hide();
            headerExtIsOpen = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/8dCnh/

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to remember the state, just use toggle()

```
$(function () {
    setMenu();    
});

function setMenu()
{
    $('#headerExt').hide();

    $('#header').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#headerExt').toggle();
    });
}
```

---

You said you want to toggle other things.

Best thing would be to toggle a class to change the color

```
$('#header').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $('#headerExt').toggle();
});

another way is to check the state

$('#header').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var child = $('#headerExt').toggle();
    var isOpen = child.is(":visibile");
    $(this).css("background-color" : isOpen ? "red" : "blue" );
});
```

---

if the layout is something like

```
<div class="portlet">
   <h2><a href="#">Header</a></h2>
   <div>
      <p>Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can have CSS like this

```
.portlet h2 { background-color: yellow; }
.portlet > div { display: none; }
.portlet.open h2 { background-color: green; }
.portlet.open > div { display: block; }
```

And the JavaScript

```
$(".portlet h2 a").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".portlet").toggleClass("open");
});
```

And there is layouts where it would be possible to have zero JavaScript involved.

Comment: I will also set some css properties later, so toggle won't work then.

Comment: background color of header itself when the Ext is open. I set it back to normal again when Ext closes. So I need to know when it's already open or not I guess

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had some script hidden in my .js file that closes the menu again when the user clicks elsewhere, that I forgot about.

```
function resetMenu(e) {
    var container = $('#headerExt');

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $('#header').css("background-color", "inherit");
        container.hide();
        headerExtIsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

I forgot to set the headerExtIsOpen back to false again after closing it in this function (code above shows the fix). Now it works fine :)